# Ruby on rails application with daily db:migrate:rebuild

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

We have a ruby on rails app with a postgres database.  As the data is ever changing we need to run a daily db:migrate:rebuild.

Currently when we run these tasks the site is taken down for a number of hours, and the passenger queue fills up on the server which takes down the other apps on the server.  Looking for the most cost effective way of resolving this

My plan to stop this is to

- Create a secondary database server
- Configure a postgres replication from the master to the secondary
  slave.
- Configure the db:migrate:rebuild to run on the slave server
- Replicate the new db back to a new database on the master server, and update
  the database.yml file to point to the new database
- Restart nginx

A few questions:

How easy is it to configure the db:migrate to happen on the other db server?  Do I just create a new rails environment called for example replica with the database details in?  Then run

```
RAILS_ENV=replica bundle exec db:migrate:rebuild
```

Also will this still cause the passenger queue to fill up still?

Trying to avoid horizontal scaling of the web servers etc, as budget is still limited.

Here is the rake task definition:-

```
namespace :db do
namespace :migrate do
 desc "Run custom sql scripts"
 task :sql => :environment do
   ['helpers', 'mviews', 'plpgsql'].each do |dir|
     files = Dir.glob(Rails.root.join("db/#{dir}/*.sql"))
     files.sort.each do |file|
       puts file
       ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(File.read(file))
     end
   end
 end
 desc "Rebuild all computed values"
 task :rebuild => :migrate do
   Sapi.rebuild
 end
 end
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `db:rebuild` task about?

Comment: Why do you need to run `db:migrate` on a daily basis? Why not just when you need to change the database schema during a deployment? This sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me.

Comment: task should be db:migrate:rebuild  - have added the rake task definition

Comment: But it just infers `Sapi.rebuild`, so it is still not clear what does it do really... Yes, I see it "rebuilds computed values" but what does it mean? Could you maybe share an example?

Comment: You know as much as me....i've been told we do a daily database rebuild, you need to come up with a solution to stop the site from going down.

Comment: I don't think the problem can be solved without the proper diagnosis. What makes the rebuild process so devastating? Does it contain some blocking operations? Or it is just about very slow queries over the large row sets? How was it _supposed_ to work? (let's imagine the rebuild process doesn't kill the app anymore but still takes hours to complete - what should happen to the database writes that happened after the rebuild process started and can affect the computed values?)